# Angular 4 Internationalization and Routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm working on a project for work that is using angular 4's native routing and i18n internationalization. The problem that I'm encountering is when the user switches languages while on a route that is not the primary route. This part of the application is accessed like `foo.com/admin/` and when we throw a language in there, the app reloads to `foo.com/admin/es/`. If this is done from a route such as `foo.com/admin/settings` the problem is the application will reload to the language but the result would be a message `Cannot get admin/es/settings`.

The only way this can be avoided is for the user to change language on the main route. I understand the changes of this happening are probably minimal but I feel that we are not using routes correctly as I have been pushing for a better structure to our routes utilizing child routes. I'm very familiar with child routes in AngularJS and ui.router.

So I'm really down to a two-part question:
1. How can our routing and internationalization work together?
2. How do we achieve a better structure for our routes?
  a. Would ui.router for Angular 2 be a better option? (I'm really pushing for this but I've not yet tried ui.router and angular-cli)

Current Route Mapping:

- foo.com/admin

  - /user
  - /invite
  - /settings
  - /publications-added
  - /publications-cited
  - /publications-read
  - /publications-viewed
  - /library-views

Desired Rout Mapping:

- fo.com/admin

  - /user

    - /invite
  - /settings
  - /analytics

    - /publications-added
    - /publications-cited
    - /publications-read
    - /publications-viewed
    - /library-views

Routing:

     `{
        path: '',
        component: BaseComponent,
        resolve: {
          user: UserService
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: AdminUserComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'invite',
            component: AdminInviteComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'settings',
            component: AdminSettingsComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'publications-added',
            component: AdminAnalyticsComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'publications-cited',
            component: AdminAnalyticsComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'publications-read',
            component: AdminAnalyticsComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'publications-viewed',
            component: AdminAnalyticsComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'library-views',
            component: AdminAnalyticsComponent,
            canActivate: [AdminUserGuard]
          },
          {
            path: 'analytics',
            redirectTo: 'publications-added',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          }
        ]
      }`

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the real solution to my issue is the default routing strategy angular 4 uses. By switching to the HashLocationStrategy, this resolved the issue.

However, Dmitry's suggestion wouldn't work for my situation since English is our default language, and it doesn't build in its own language directory. If we had it set up that way, then it would be a viable solution. Thank you Dmitry!